# Laravel: How does dependecy injection with type hint work?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

If one uses in a controller something like

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        //...
```

then whenever the function `send()` is called without input, Laravel [will automatically resolve the `Request` object from the Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection). **But where and how is this magic happening?**

I checked the abstract class `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` which only has 4 methods, and none of theme seems to do the trick. I also noticed that if I do something like

```
class ContactController 
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
       //...
```

then whenever calling `send()` this will throw an `Too few arguments to function..` error.

I don't know where else to look. If I google my question, I find plenty of post explaining how to use `type hint` but not how it actually works.

So where is the piece of code that resolves the object from the Service Container if I type hint it in a controller?

Comment: like literally what is calling the method on your controller via the container?

Comment: It is not about type hinting, it's about Dependency Injection and DI Container. Google it.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs thats correct, I rephrased the question title for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually doesn't use the container to call your controller method oddly enough even though the controller itself is resolved from the container (which would give you constructor injection from the container)

`Illuminate\Routing\Route@run` -> `runController()` ->

`Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher` uses `Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait`

`resolveClassMethodDependencies() -> resolveMethodDependencies()` ... during this process is where the container is used to resolve instances for the dependencies that were gathered by direct reflection.

The `ControllerDispatcher` ends up calling your method and passing the resolved parameters to it.

It is doing what would seem similar to the container's `call` method.